# Looping a sound is not working in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna-4.0

i have added a piece of code to have a *wav file looped in my Visual C# 2010 express edition Project game (i ve added wav file in content folder project as well in debug folder) , but it plays only 1 time till end then it stops. the code i ve added is these :

```
 SoundEffect sound;
 sound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("bonus_music"); 
 SoundEffectInstance instance = sound.CreateInstance();
 instance.IsLooped = true;
 sound.Play();
```

it is not looping that sound. im using XNA Game Studio 4.0 (with this no problem at all to loop sound, it works perfectly), but i want loop that sound without using XNA , and i followed sample on MSDN reference and library and even in this forum for looping sound in C#).

what am i doing wrong ? any suggest ? i thought that code was OK.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently playing the `SoundEffect` (which isn't looped) rather than the `SoundEffectInstance` (which is). Try changing the final line to

```
instance.Play();
```